# Required files to deploy a Console Application from my Dev server to Live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I have created my first console application using Visual studio 2012, and i provided the following inside my main method:-

```
class Program
    {
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SkillManagementEntities sd = new SkillManagementEntities())
            {
                //code goes here
                sd.SaveChanges();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

now I want to deploy this console application to another server (live server), so I have copied the .application file from the following location inside my console application "\bin\debug":-

[image]

then I run the application inside my live server using windows command prompt, but I got the following error :-

> 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c5 61934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified . at
> ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)"

now I tried copying the other files and I ended up having these 4 files inside my live server :-

[image]

now the .exe file runs correctly inside my live server, but not sure how I can know which files I need to have inside my live server, and are copying these 4 files inside my live server the correct way to deploy a console

Comment: You should show file extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You need your EXE file, DLLs for any libraries you use, and usually the `exe.config` file (if you have any configuration in it, such as connection strings in App.config).

You do not need:

- `.dll.xml` files (these are just XML doc comments for Visual Studio)
- PDBs (these are just for debugging)
- `.vshost.exe` (this is a stub used by Visual Studio)
- `.exe.manifest` (this tells Windows about UAC compatibility; it typically isn't very relevant)

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help. so in my case I need 3 files; EntityFramework.dll + consoleapplication1.exe of type XML configuration file + consoleapplication1 of type application ,,, is this correct ?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain but in my case I did not copy the exe.manifest and the .application file worked correctly ,,, so why I need to have this copied inside my live server? ?

Comment: so in my case I need 3 files; EntityFramework.dll + consoleapplication1.exe of type XML configuration file + consoleapplication1 of type application ,,, is this correct ?

Comment: @JohnJohn: Turn on file extensions so you can see what your files actually are.